# Trying to determine arcosine without tables/calculator/etc

Tags: trigonometry

I find myself in a situation where I must determine the arcosine of a given number (eg. acos(x)) using only basic mathematical functions (add, subtract, multiply and divide.) I agree this is a stupid position to be in, but here I am.

Not being a mathematician, I'm hoping someone here can guide me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think we need more context. Do you need to calculate this for any $x$ or do you have a specific $x$ in mind?

Comment: @jacer21 I need to calculate this for any "x"

Comment: The accos value is part of a larger equation (after determining acos, that value gets converted to degrees); the "x" value being fed to the acos function gets calculated previously

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f(x)=\arccos(x)$.

$$f'(x)=\frac{-1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$

$$=-(1-x^2)^{\frac{-1}{2}}$$

$$=-1-\frac{1}{2}x^2-\frac{3}{8}x^4 ....$$

$$\implies \arccos(x)=\frac{\pi}{2}-x-\frac{1}{6}x^3-\frac{3}{40}x^5...$$

Answer (score 0):

what about using its Taylor expansion ? http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=series(acos(x))&t=crmtb01

first terms: pi/2 - x - x³/6 - 3x⁵/40